# PyO3 convert rust struct to &PyAny

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

I have a struct

```
#[pyclass]
pub struct DynMat {
   ...
}
```

and I have this function

```
#[pyfunction]
#[text_signature = "(tensor/)"]
pub fn exp<'py>(py: Python<'py>, tensor_or_scalar: &'py PyAny) -> PyResult<&'py PyAny> {
    // I need to return &PyAny because I might either return PyFloat or DynMat
    if let Ok(scalar) = tensor_or_scalar.cast_as::<PyFloat>() {
        let scalar: &PyAny = PyFloat::new(py, scalar.extract::<f64>()?.exp());
        Ok(scalar)
    } else if let Ok(tensor) = tensor_or_scalar.cast_as::<PyCell<DynMat>>() {
        let mut tensor:PyRef<DynMat> = tensor.try_borrow()?;
        let tensor:DynMat = tensor.exp()?;
        // what now? How to return tensor
    }
}
```

The question is, how can I return a Rust struct marked with `pyclass` from a function that expects `PyResult<&'py PyAny>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it's the `tensor` you want to return.

If your return type was `PyResult<DynMat>` you could just return that and let automatic conversion kick in. But I assume depending on whether you have a scalar or a tensor you will return different types.

So, right now you have `tensor` as a `DynMat` in an *owned value*, and we need to move that to the python heap. Here's how that looks like:

```rust
let tensor_as_py = Py::new(py, tensor)?.into_ref(py);
return Ok(tensor_as_py);
```

PS: You can write your attempt at conversion more concisely too:

```rust
pub fn blablabla() {
  let tensor: PyRefMut<DynMat> = tensor_or_scalar.extract();
  if let Ok(tensor) = tensor {
    let tensor = tensor.exp();
```

But looking at your code, there's one more thing that's confusing me:

To exponentiate the tensor, you're borrowing it mutably. That suggests to me that the exponentiation will be *in place*. So why do you then need to return it, too?

Or is this meant to be a reference back to the original tensor? In that case, I'd get rid of the variable shadowing so that you can just return the `PyRefMut<DynMat>`, which you can convert to a `&PyAny` via `from` or `into`.

But actually, `tensor.exp()?` seems to be return an owned value of type `DynMat`, so it seems like a *new* tensor is created after all. In that case, yes, you need to move it from Rust to the python heap with the `Py::new` method shown above.

EDIT:
Previous version used `as_ref(py)` instead of `into_ref(py)`. The former *borrows* from the `Py<_>` object to give you a reference, but the latter actually *consumes* the `Py<_>` object.

The documentation actually explains exactly your use case here https://docs.rs/pyo3/0.13.2/pyo3/prelude/struct.Py.html#method.into_ref

Comment: I have a problem with borrow checker. If I take the reference like you say
`Py::new(py, tensor)?.as_ref(py)`, I get `temporary value created here` and `returns a value referencing data owned by the current function`. How can I make sure that lifetime `'py` is used by the created reference?

Comment: Ah. I hadn't actually tried compiling and assumed the IDE would tell me about this issue :D 

Simple typo, see my edit.